# English phrase or word to describe a scenario where people say something that is completely unrelated to the conversation or topic

Tags: phrase-requests, latin

I think the phrase I'm looking for has Latin roots. Ad... Something. But I just can't remember it for some reason. Can someone help?

Comment: Related: [List of Latin phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(full)).

Comment: Are you thinking of _non sequitur_?

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes!!!! That's the one. I can't believe I was searching around for words beginning with "ad"